What is the best practice for storing documents in Firestore?
A Car has a Brand. So, many Cars have the same Brand.
How do you do to map these objects to store in the Firestore? What is the best practice for that?
We need to think that a Brand can change, so we need to change the Brand only once to affect all the cars.
Car {
 String carName;
 Brand brand;
}

Brand {
 String brandName;
}

So, what is the best option to store a Car on a Firestore document (no-SQL)?
I think the best option is the 2, so is there any best practice way for it to be performant when reading the data from Firestore?

Store all cars data:

- Document Car 1:
Car {
 carName: "Corolla"
 brand: {
  brandName: "Toyota"
 }
}

- Document Car 2:
Car {
 carName: "Land Cruiser"
 brand: {
  brandName: "Toyota"
 }
}

So, "Toyota" brand will repeat in all cars with this brand.

Reference the Brand document:

- Document Car 1:
Car {
 carName: "Corolla"
 brand: "abcd-efgh-brand-code"
}

- Document Car 2:
Car {
 carName: "Land Cruiser"
 brand: "abcd-efgh-brand-code"
}

- Document Brand:
Brand {
 documentId: "abcd-efgh-brand-code"
 brand: "Toyota"
}


Choose the option that enables your expected queries.  Outside of that, it's entirely an opinion, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

"we need to change the Brand only once to affect all the cars" It sounds like may be coming from a background/education in relational databases. Trying to apply such SQL reasoning to a NoSQL database is typically not the best way to make use of them, as a different set of rules apply there. To learn about data modeling for NoSQL and Firestore, I recommend reading NoSQL data modeling techniques and watching Get to know Firestore.

There is no "right" answer or even "best practice" here. Both solutions will work and be performant. However, as the data scales, denormalizing the data will be more performant and cost less. But it's subjective - ultimately the queries being run will drive the structure, but then programmatically, using a reference can be a tad more flexible but at a higher cost. If the cost difference is $.12 a month then well, it doesn't really matter - it becomes a cost vs benefit choice.


A Car has a Brand. So, many Cars have the same Brand. How do you map this object to store in the Firestore?

As you already showed us in your Car class. However, since you only have a single field inside the Brand class, I cannot see any benefit of using a class in the first place. Besides that, having a car/brand/brandName it looks redundant to me. So due to the fact that the car brand is a string, then I would change the declaration of the Car class like this:
Car {
 String carName;
 String brandName; // <--
}


I think the best option is the 2.

It would have been if you had used a SQL database. Firestore is a NoSQL database. So holding just a reference to another document might not be the best solution here. Please bear in mind that in NoSQL-type databases there is no concept of a JOIN clause. So in order to have faster and cheaper queries, all the data you need to be returned by a query should exist in the documents that are returned.
It's true that you can have a separate distinct collection for the brands if you need to query the brands of the cars separately. However, in this case, having the same data in two different places is a quite common practice. As @FrankvanPuffelen already noticed, it is most likely you have a SQL background. Please remember that in the NoSQL world, we are structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. So having the brands inside the car document can be considered totally normal. This technique is called denormalization, and it's widely used in structuring NoSQL databases. For more information, I recommend reading my answer in the following post:

What is denormalization in Firebase Cloud Firestore?


hello, according to document-based DBs like MongoDB, document referencing is normal but it will lead to complex queries, secondly storing the brand in each car isn't that technique will lead to data duplication and wasted disk space? it's likely a trade off right here waste disk space to have simple queries or save it but have complex queries .

@A-E The space is always cheaper than the document reads. So it is best to have the data duplicated (denormalized).

so, it's a business decision, whether he cares about space or latency

@A-E There's a difference between MongoDB and Firebase. With MongoDB (SDK's in particular) document references are normal and is part of how their database "works". For clarity, it does NOT lead to more complex queries (who said that?). In Firebase, denormalizing is normal. Bottom line is that disk space is cheap and it's faster and cheaper to duplicate the data. Data models in Mongo are more document (think: 'object') oriented so relationships make sense for that implementation. In the OP's case though, either option would 'work' so ultimately it will depend on the queries.

@Alex Mamo . thank you. it's updated now.

Hey there. Did my answer/comments help? Can I help you with other information?

This is Data Normalization
which is concerned with avoiding duplicated data.
Look, for your question both techniques are approximately allocate the same disk space since brand contains only one field (not guaranteed to still have one field  in the future), but using the reference technique will definitely prevent data duplication and allow easy brand-update for all cars (docs).
So in the future, changing one doc (brand) will be listened by all docs (Cars), and adding more field in brand doc will save more space comparing with technique 1 (Nested Docs eg: brand inside a car). this is more suitable for SQLDBs.
BUT
For NOSQL DBs both techniques have different effects and usecases,

technique 1 : is a denormalized form of data, although it's
(duplicated data) but it help to make read query more faster at the
expense of storage space. which is preferable for most NOSQL DBs
(because disk space is more cheaper than latency).
technique 2: although it saves more disk space but it makes read time
more longer which definitely affects the performance.

At last, it's a trade-off choose which is suitable to satisfy your requirements.

NoSQL benefits from Denormalizing data. Take a look at this answer for a great explanation.

@Jay, thank you . it's updated now
